# How to change location of activemq-data folder in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic

I need to change data folder of my embedded activemq instance. I use `spring-boot-starter-activemq` which creates folder `activemq-data` in maven `$baseDir` folder. I would like to move it to `target` folder to be able to remove the folder with command `mvn clean`.

I found only the following article, but when I pass system property `activemq.store.dir` to my integration test then it does not work.
http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-change-the-message-store-directory-for-an-embedded-broker.html

I tried to find out if it is possible to setup it in `application.properties` file but it seems it is not possible:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/activemq/ActiveMQProperties.java

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot doesn't auto-configure the embedded mode for ActiveMQ. Everything is done at the activeMQ level so you should refer to their documentation. As you've noted already, you should set the `activemq.store.dir` *system property*.

If you try to set a regular Spring Boot property in your integration test, this isn't going to be a system property so that won't work. Also, if you try to set the system property in a `@Before` it will be set too late as the context will have been already s.tarted

I fail to see why you need a persistent broker for integration tests, looks like a smell to me. How about let Spring Boot do its thing? If you don't configure any broker URL, you'll get `vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false` and that's not going to create any directory at all.

Comment: Yes, non-persistent broker would be better for integration test but there is one problem.

Comment: Yes, non-persistent broker would be better for integration test but there is one problem. I can find the following messages in the log:

1. ActiveMQ is started
2. Camel sends message to my queue
3. ActiveMQ is stopped
4. ActiveMQ is started
5. JMS client receive message
6. ActiveMQ is stopped

When there is not consumer ActiveMQ is stopped. I can only receive message asynchronously before I invoke camel message.

Answer (score 1):

After some debugging I found out that I have to use different system property: `org.apache.activemq.default.directory.prefix`.

https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-broker/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/util/IOHelper.java#L60